# AccessViolationException when setting/receiving callback

Tags: c#, c++, callback, interop, access-violation

I'm trying to recreate the StreamingPreview sample from Blackmagic Design's DeckLink SDK in C# using [DeckLink.net](https://github.com/simongh/DeckLink.net) dll.

When I run the code below, it seems to work: the notifications get installed and I even receive the device arrived event (and I can query the device's properties too) but I get an **AccessViolationException**. It must be connected to the streamingDiscovery.InstallDeviceNotifications() line, and I only get it when I actually have a device plugged in and therefore receive a notification.

Could you kindly help me?

My C# code:

```
class DeckLink : IBMDStreamingDeviceNotificationCallback
{
    // Native values
    private static int S_OK = 0;
    private static int E_FAIL = 1;

    int result;

    private IBMDStreamingDiscovery streamingDiscovery;

    public DeckLink()
    {
        try
        {
            streamingDiscovery = (IBMDStreamingDiscovery)new StreamingDiscovery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This application requires the Blackmagic Streaming drivers installed.\nPlease install the Blackmagic Streaming drivers to use the features of this application.");
            goto bail;
        }
        result = streamingDiscovery.InstallDeviceNotifications(this);
        if (result == E_FAIL)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to install device notifications for the Blackmagic Streaming devices");
            goto bail;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Device notifications for the Blackmagic Streaming devices were successfully installed");
        return;

    bail:
        if (streamingDiscovery != null)
        {
            streamingDiscovery = null;
        }
        return;
    }

    public int StreamingDeviceArrived(Blackmagic.DeckLink.IDeckLink device)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Device arrived");
        return S_OK;
    }

    public int StreamingDeviceModeChanged(Blackmagic.DeckLink.IDeckLink device, Blackmagic.DeckLink.BMDStreamingDeviceMode mode)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int StreamingDeviceRemoved(Blackmagic.DeckLink.IDeckLink device)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And these are from the SDK's C++ sample:

```
result = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CBMDStreamingDiscovery, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IBMDStreamingDiscovery, (void**)&m_streamingDiscovery);
if (FAILED(result))
{
    MessageBox(_T("This application requires the Blackmagic Streaming drivers installed.\nPlease install the Blackmagic Streaming drivers to use the features of this application."), _T("Error"));
    goto bail;
}

// Note: at this point you may get device notification messages!
result = m_streamingDiscovery->InstallDeviceNotifications(this);
if (FAILED(result))
{
    MessageBox(_T("Failed to install device notifications for the Blackmagic Streaming devices"), _T("Error"));
    goto bail;
}
```

C++ QueryInterface:

```
if (ppv == NULL)
    return E_POINTER;
*ppv = NULL;

if (iid == IID_IUnknown)
{
    *ppv = static_cast<IUnknown*>(static_cast<IBMDStreamingDeviceNotificationCallback*>(this));
    AddRef();
    result = S_OK;
}
else if (iid == IID_IBMDStreamingDeviceNotificationCallback)
{
    *ppv = static_cast<IBMDStreamingDeviceNotificationCallback*>(this);
    AddRef();
    result = S_OK;
}
else if (iid == IID_IBMDStreamingH264InputCallback)
{
    *ppv = static_cast<IBMDStreamingH264InputCallback*>(this);
    AddRef();
    result = S_OK;
}

return result;
```

I've also uploaded the SDK's sample and the dotNet library [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_1SYs_lWVzGcm9yalYtZ3dRUG8&usp=sharing).